# ZAP Session Analysis Dialogue isn't displaying after generating the 20000 tokens

Tags: session, token, analysis, zap

I am doing the JSESSIONID token analysis of my web application and can generate as many session tokens as I wish. The trouble is, after generating the tokens, the Session Token Analysis Dialogue which is supposed to open is not opening. Is there other way of opening this dialogue?

By default ZAP generates 20000 tokens, but I was generating 2000 only, so thought this could be the issue. But no matter how many or few I generate the dialogue still doesn't open.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the application is still responding? It might have locked up, or could be deliberately holding on to the connection and not replying as an anti automation technique.

Comment: yes, the application is still responding

Comment: What version of: ZAP, token gen, java?

Comment: Disregard, I was able to recreate with the current release version (12). However, it seems to work fine when built from the current dev branch. I'll suggest to the core team that a new release be done.

Answer (score 0):

TokenGen v13 has been released which fixes this issue. It is now available via the marketplace:
[image]

Or [manual download](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/releases/tag/tokengen-v13).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I updated Token Generator to V13 and the issue is fixed completely.

Thank you all